# Popup.js not receiving message from background.js. Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, manifest, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, browser-extension

I am trying to send a message from background.js to popup.js whenever the current tab url changes for a chrome extension but getting Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist. I am using manifest version 3.
Here is the message sending code for background.js:

```
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener((activeInfo) => {
  chrome.tabs.get(activeInfo.tabId, (tab) => {
    isRedditTab = tab.url.includes('reddit.com');

    chrome.storage.local.set({ isRedditTab: isRedditTab }, () => {
      console.log("isRedditTab value saved to local storage.");
    });
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ type: 'checkReddit', isRedditTab: isRedditTab });
    console.log("message sent from background" + isRedditTab)
  });
});
```

Relevant part of popup.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message) {
    if (message.type === 'checkReddit') {
        console.log("message received in popup" + message.isRedditTab)
    }
});
```

I have tried various methods but the message is not getting received by popup.js

Comment: The popup cannot receive messages when it's closed. You can suppress the error by adding `.catch(() => {})` after sendMessage.

Comment: @wOxxOm I tried that and yes it doesn't give the error but the message still isn't received as it should be. How do I send a message from the background script to the popup script in manifest v3?

Comment: You can receive the message only when the popup is open. Assuming it's open you probably look in the wrong console. Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu.

Comment: @wOxxOm is there no way to communicate between background.js and popup.js while the popup is not open? I want to send a message from background to popup script every time the tab URL changes

Comment: No. There's no way.